# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb) in logged in app with no data on Parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform

Im trying to make the login form as the main initial screen but i cant, all the time opens user list table first. I dont have any data on Parse but i have all the neccessary classes there. It looks like it have logged in as anonymous user or something and now it makes a lot of errors because there is no suitable code for unknown user? Can somebody help me please?

```
    //
//  FeedTableViewController.swift
//  ParseStarterProject
//
//  Created by Rob Percival on 19/05/2015.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Parse. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Parse

class FeedTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var messages = [String]()
    var usernames = [String]()
    var imageFiles = [PFFile]()
    var users = [String: String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var query = PFUser.query()

        query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

            if let users = objects {

                self.messages.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
                self.users.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
                self.imageFiles.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
                self.usernames.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

                for object in users {

                    if let user = object as? PFUser {

                        self.users[user.objectId!] = user.username!

                    }
                }
            }


            var getFollowedUsersQuery = PFQuery(className: "followers")

            getFollowedUsersQuery.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)

            getFollowedUsersQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

                if let objects = objects {

                    for object in objects {

                        var followedUser = object["following"] as! String

                        var query = PFQuery(className: "Post")

                        query.whereKey("userId", equalTo: followedUser)

                        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

                            if let objects = objects {

                                for object in objects {

                                    self.messages.append(object["message"] as! String)

                                    self.imageFiles.append(object["imageFile"] as! PFFile)

                                    self.usernames.append(self.users[object["userId"] as! String]!)

                                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                                }

                            }


                        })
                    }

                }

            }

        })

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return usernames.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! cell

        imageFiles[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data, error) -> Void in

            if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {

                myCell.postedImage.image = downloadedImage

            }

        }



        myCell.username.text = usernames[indexPath.row]

        myCell.message.text = messages[indexPath.row]

        return myCell
    }


    /*
    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support editing the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
    // Delete the row from the data source
    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
    // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support rearranging the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: in what line is the error happening?

Comment: getFollowedUsersQuery.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)

Answer (score 0):

A `PFUser`'s objectID is not stored on the device. You need to fetch it. The following is Objective-C but it should be easily converted to swift.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"username"]];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        if (objects.count) {
            for (PFObject *object in objects) { // just to be safe, but there should only be one.
                NSLog(@"Object ID: %@", object.objectId);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In Swift (because you asked politely)

```
var query = PFUser.query()
query.whereKey("username", equalTo:PFUser.currentUser().objectForKey("username"))
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({(objects:NSArray, error:NSError) in
    if error == nil {
        if objects.count {
            for var object in objects {
                // here you can get object.objectID
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: can you please convert it for me to swift? exact code. I'm trying to pass this thing for several days already.. Thank you

Comment: You should know Objective-C while learning swift. I'll do my best but trust in autocomplete as I'm typing without a compiler.

Comment: I need to copy it instead of the code error place ?

Comment: Wherever you need it. If you don't understand how this works, read on how parse works. This just does a query and fetches the objectID in the background.